# Jmeter- javax.activation.MimeTypeParseException: Couldn't find the '=' that separates a parameter name from its value

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to send HTTP post request to upload .dat file using jmeter

I am getting the below error

```
[2019-11-19 10:36:19.587] ERROR   org.mule.runtime.core.internal.exception.OnErrorPropagateHandler [[MuleRuntime].cpuLight.01: [*****-sys-1-0-dit].es-oracle-sys-main.CPU_LITE @51efa03c]: event:6c5213c0-0ab8-11ea-afa5-0699867ea6c5 
********************************************************************************
Message               : MediaType cannot be parsed: application/json;charset=UTF-8;multipart/form-data.
Element               : es-******-sys-main/processors/1 @ ****-es-oracle-sys-1-0-dit:es-****-sys.xml:30
Element XML           : <apikit:router config-ref="es-oracle-sys-config"></apikit:router>
Error type            : MULE:UNKNOWN
FlowStack             : at es-****-sys-main(es-oracle-sys-main/processors/1 @ ****-es-oracle-sys-1-0-dit:es-oracle-sys.xml:30) 0 ms
Payload Type          : org.mule.runtime.core.internal.streaming.bytes.ManagedCursorStreamProvider
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Root Exception stack trace:
javax.activation.MimeTypeParseException: Couldn't find the '=' that separates a parameter name from its value.
    at javax.activation.MimeTypeParameterList.parse(MimeTypeParameterList.java:116)
    at javax.activation.MimeTypeParameterList.<init>(MimeTypeParameterList.java:67)
    at javax.activation.MimeType.parse(MimeType.java:120)
    at javax.activation.MimeType.<init>(MimeType.java:63)
    at org.mule.runtime.api.metadata.MediaType.parse(MediaType.java:102)
    at org.mule.module.apikit.CharsetUtils.getCharset(CharsetUtils.java:207)
    at org.mule.module.apikit.api.validation.RequestValidator.getHeaderCharset(RequestValidator.java:149)
    at org.mule.module.apikit.api.validation.RequestValidator.getCharset(RequestValidator.java:133)
    at org.mule.module.apikit.api.validation.RequestValidator.validate(RequestValidator.java:82)
    at org.mule.module.apikit.api.validation.RequestValidator.validate(RequestValidator.java:53)
    at org.mule.module.apikit.Router.doRoute(Router.java:147)
    at org.mule.module.apikit.Router.processEvent(Router.java:134)
    at org.mule.module.apikit.Router.processWithExtension(Router.java:122)
    at org.mule.runtime.core.privileged.processor.MessageProcessors.lambda$flatMap$30(MessageProcessors.java:634)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(FluxFlatMap.java:381)

--------------------------------------------
```

From postman, i am able to get the response and below is the content type

```
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Cache-Control: no-cache
client_id: d5*****************************
client_secret: F1***********************************8
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------------694050903567678421441304
dDocTitle: Worker.dat
href: Worker.zip
Postman-Token: 55de1a27-6ec4-4483-b46e-a3e808299166
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.19.0
X-Forwarded-For: 162.44.150.10
X-Forwarded-Port: 443
X-Forwarded-Proto: https
```

I have passed all the above content and mime type. Still i am getting 500 internal error with invalid mime type

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you didn't provide [MIME Type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types) for the file:

[image]

you can try adding [`application/octet-stream`](https://kb.iu.edu/d/agtj) MIME type there and see whether it resolves your issue

---

Going forward given your request works fine in Postman you can just record the call from Postman using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder)

1. [Start JMeter's HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html)
2. [Configure Postman to use JMeter as the proxy](https://support.getpostman.com/hc/en-us/articles/360008893713-How-do-I-configure-Postman-to-work-through-a-proxy-):

   [image]
3. Copy your `Worker.dat` file to bin folder of your JMeter installation (this is required so JMeter could parse the request from Postman and properly build [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler, see [Recording File Uploads with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/recording-file-uploads-jmeter/) for details)
4. Run your request in Postman
5. JMeter should capture the request and store it under the [Recording Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Recording_Controller)

Comment: Thank you, Recording controller worked. Mime type is application/octet-stream Mime